# Problem with postfix packages

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, debian-etch

I've been trying to install postfix and dovecot on my Debian server, but when I run apt-get install postfix, I get this error:

Err http://ftp2.de.debian.org etch/main ssl-cert 1.0.14
  404 Not Found [IP: 195.71.68.86 80]
Failed to fetch ssl-cert_1.0.14_all.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 195.71.68.86 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the message, this error is often caused by failing to run `apt-get update`.

As root, run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install postfix
```

Comment: Tried this and got a number of failed to fetch errors, which leads me to believe that greenmang is probably right...

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here [ http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ ] "etch" is listed nowhere.

Whereas if you check [ http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/dists/ ] shows that "etch" has been moved to archives or old-stable.

So it is recommanded that you upgrade your distro to current stable i.e. Lenny.

The security support is also terminated to "etch"

[ http://www.debian.org/News/2010/20100121 ]

Comment: How do I go about upgrading a vps debian? Is there an apt package for that?

Comment: To upgrade from etch to lenny check following link


http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-upgrade-from-debian-etch-40-to-lenny-50.html



Just make sure that instead of replacing "etch" with "lenny", replace "etch" with "stable"

That way you will always have stable branch of Debian and will never have to worry about
etch / lenny / squeeze or whatever.

This is what I follow on my servers. So for VPS Debian procedure shouldn't be different.